# How do I make NaN numeric values to be lower than any other numeric value.during comparisons?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Bottomline, I want  In a comparison, NaN numeric values to be lower than any other numeric value.

Lets say I have s1 and s2,

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 3, np.nan, 5, np.nan, -1, np.nan])
s2 = pd.Series([2, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, -1])
```

When I compare them as s1 < s2 then I want the following behavior:

```
Out: 
0    True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    True
5    False
6    True
```

Comment: corrected it. np.nan instead of .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply with [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) function and [`np.NINF`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/constants.html?highlight=ninf#numpy.NINF) constant:

```
In [256]: s2.fillna(np.NINF) > s1.fillna(np.NINF)                                                                                              
Out[256]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
dtype: bool
```

- `np.NINF` - NumPy constant, floating point representation of negative infinity

Answer (score 4):

Use an `or` condition to fix rows where `s1` is null and `s2` is not.

```
(s1 < s2) | (s1.isnull() & s2.notnull())
#0     True
#1    False
#2    False
#3    False
#4     True
#5    False
#6     True
#dtype: bool
```

Comment: pretty nice answer!